# trouble selecting a period of dates in Pandas with < and >

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

a really simple question perhaps, but it's my first time working with pandas already and I'm having trouble slicing up my dataframes into smaller ones based on dates.

So, i have a dataframe (named `firstreadin`) that looks like this (and thousands more rows):

```
        date               numbers  megaball
0 1999-01-12     [5, 7, 9, 20, 46]         2
1 1999-01-08   [5, 21, 23, 26, 37]         3
2 1999-01-05   [4, 31, 32, 34, 43]        19
3 1999-01-01  [11, 19, 28, 43, 48]         5
4 1998-12-29     [3, 5, 7, 28, 35]        10
```

and i want to slice them into a couple periods given specific date dividers, and while I'm having no trouble specifying the first and last periods, i can't seem to specify the middle periods:

```
#firsttime and secondtime are the date separators
firsttime = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/13/99', '%m/%d/%y')
secondtime = datetime.datetime.strptime('5/15/02', '%m/%d/%y')

firstperiod = firstreadin[firstreadin.date < firsttime].reset_index(drop=True)
thirdperiod = firstreadin[firstreadin.date > secondtime].reset_index(drop=True)
```

i can't get the secondperiod! (the one between firsttime and secondtime). 
I've tried this:

```
secondperiod = firstreadin[firstreadin.date >= firsttime and firstreadin.date < secondtime]
```

but this just gives me `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What's going on and how should I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.logical_and`: numpy.logical_and(a, b)

```
    secondperiod = firstreadin[numpy.logical_and(firstreadin.date >= firsttime, firstreadin.date < secondtime)]
```

I hope this can help you!